# Why does Fedora 20 still deny access to home directories after enabling SELinux httpd_read_user_content and setting files to httpd_user_content_t?

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, apache-2.4, selinux

On my Fedora 20, I've learned that to allow write access to files by processes like PHP via Apache, the process owner, which is in my case `apache`, must have write permissions to the files. Also, since SELinux is enabled, the files must have the `httpd_system_rw_content_t` context.

It also looks like an SELinux policy prevents httpd from accessing any files under `/home`. Just about everyone agrees that to remedy this, the files you want accessed must have security context `httpd_user_content_t` or `httpd_user_rw_content_t`. I've been sure to do this, yet Apache still says it does not have permission to access the directories. When those files don't have the user_content context, I indeed get SELinux warnings. When the context is set, I don't get the warnings, but Apache still can't access the files. Everything under `/home/me/game` has the following user permissions and security context:

```
$ sudo chcon -Rv --type=httpd_user_rw_content_t game
$ sudo setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
$ sudo chown -R :apache game
$ ll -Zd game
drwxrwxr-x. me apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_rw_content_t:s0 game
```

Yet Apache tells me:

### Forbidden

**You don't have permission to access /game on this server.**

Might anyone know what else I could check?

Comment: According to http://selinuxproject.org/page/ApacheRecipes, contexts should be correct if you use `public_html` as folder name. Try a `restorecon -Rv /home`. If you still have issues, take a look at `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: What do the permissions to your home directory look like? Are you sure that `apache` can read the file according to the UNIX permissions? `apache` needs at least eXecute on `/`, `/home`, `/home/me` and the directory itself.

Comment: Run the test again then run `ausearch -ts recent -m avc` and provide the output.

Comment: Everything under my home directory is owned by `me`, but I'm not sure about explicitly giving `apache` read or write permissions to all of `/` or `/home` because I can host things under `/var/www/` without issue. From what I see, the files need not be associated with `apache` at all for read access, but `apache` must have write permission on anything a server script wants to edit. Everything there is labeled `httpd_sys_content_t`, but that same context in my home directory isn't making a difference...

Comment: I've made sure the context of /home/me/public_html is `httpd_user_content_t`. It still can't access it. I'm running the command `sudo ausearch -ts recent -m avc` but the only output is `<no matches>` No SELinux warnings, though...

Comment: Stressing Jorn's point again: Your **/home/me** directory likely needs to be world readable+executable. Try `su apache` and enter the directory. Identify which one doesn't allow you. Then find the reason, both in terms of permissions and context.

Comment: That certainly makes since. From what I see, `/` and `/home` are both world readable and executable, as is the case with `/var/www` and the files under `/home/me/public_html`.

    $ ll -dZ /
    drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0  /
    $ ll -dZ /home
    drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 /home
    $ ll -dZ /home/me/public_html
    drwxrwxr-x. me me unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_user_content_t:s0 /home/me/public_html

This is a tricky one...

Comment: Could you please add the relevant portions of your `apache` configuration? (WRT `mod_userdir`, `UserDir` directive, ...), anything useful in the `apache` logs? What's the output of `getsebool httpd_read_user_content`?

Comment: In my base config file, `mod_userdir.so` is being loaded. Although I wasn't particularly interested in what `UserDir` provides as far as URLs with usernames after a tilde, that doesn't appear to be working either.

However, I did notice this in the Apache error log: 
`(13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:38594] AH00035: access to /game/ denied (filesystem path '/home/me/game') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path`

Search permissions??

Comment: Okay, hopefully I find some help here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied Jorn and Felix, you may be right that file permissions still aren't in order...

Comment: Aaaah! Silly me... `/home/me` was not world readable nor executable. Answer coming in a minute... You guys were a huge help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh... always check your permissions, people. Even though the SELinux settings were good, there was a directory on the way down to the path I wanted `apache` to reach that was not allowing that user to read/execute it.

First of all, I should have looked at `/var/log/httpd/error_log` which plainly said:

> (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:38628] AH00035: access to /game/ denied (filesystem >path '/home/me/game') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Looking up the error on Google, I found [this page](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied) that also spells out the issue. Since it had no problem serving things from `/var/www` I checked the directory permissions all the way down:

```
$ ll -d /
drwxr-xr-x. 18 root root 4096 Jun 22 18:52 /
$ ll -d /var
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root root 4096 Jun 22 12:51 /var
$ ll -d /var/www
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root 4096 Jun 21 09:19 /var/www
```

I did the same all the way down my home dirs:

```
$ ll -d /home
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 Jun 13 21:31 /home
$ ll -d /home/me
drwx------. 35 me me 4096 Jun 22 19:05 /home/me
```

Yep... a simple `sudo chmod o=rx /home/me` got me up and going. I couldn't have done it without checking everything you guys asked me to, and I thank you.